# No disk on an openstack instance

Tags: centos, instance, openstack

I am using OpenStack packstack Train release. I want to create a Centos 7 instance using an ISO file. I run the following commands:

```
glance image-create --name "centos" --file CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1908.iso  \
                    --disk-format iso --container-format bare --visibility public
```

I create after that the instance:

```
openstack server create --flavor m1.medium --image centos VM               \
                        --nic net-id=9b6e4c51-3955-4603-b0aa-7aa739de7db3  \
                        --security-group 8a5e9d72-752c-4d3f-be9a-35bc9a7c30a5
```

Until now everything is working fine, but when I go to check the console, and start the Centos installation, I find that no disk is available to create the instance. How can I solve that please ?

Comment: You need a volume as the second disk. The first disk is the DVDROM. Why do you want to boot from an ISO file in the first place? [Centos cloud images](https://cloud.centos.org/centos/) are available.

Comment: @berndbausch i want to use centos with the GUI, i tried once with the cloud image but i've got only the command line

Comment: That's a valid reason. An alternative is launching an instance from a normal cloud image, then installing the GUI on it. In any case, when launching the instance from an ISO image, you need to give it a second disk.